# Limit of the sequence when another sequence is given

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose if $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$ and $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_n = 5$. Then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$.
My guess is it will be 0.2 (1/5). But I am not sure how would I prove this. How should one approach such a problem?

Comment: A tail of $(b_n)_n$ being within $\varepsilon$ of $1/5$ requires that the same tail of $(a_n)_n$ is within some small distance of $5$...

Comment: Does that mean it won't always be 1/5 and depends on $a_n$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!